# changing startup MVC group in Application.groovy issue

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, griffon

I've created new Groffin module using IntelliJ. I was prompted for create-app command.
Creating a module was fine, and as you know, by default, when you ran an app, it shows applet with default content "Content goes here".

Next, I've added a second **login** MVC group in Application.groovy:

```
application {
    title = 'Soms'
    startupGroups = ['login']

    // Should Griffon exit when no Griffon created frames are showing?
    autoShutdown = true

    // If you want some non-standard application class, apply it here
    //frameClass = 'javax.swing.JFrame'
}
mvcGroups {
    // MVC Group for "soms"
    'soms' {
        model      = 'soms.SomsModel'
        view       = 'soms.SomsView'
        controller = 'soms.SomsController'
    }

    // MVC Group for "login"
    'login' {
        model       = 'soms.LoginModel'
        view        = 'soms.LoginView'
        controller  = 'soms.LoginController'
    }

}
```

I've also created:

1. LoginModel.groovy (groovy class)
2. LoginController.groovy (groovy class)
3. LoginView.groovy (groovy script)

in the corresponding folders.

When I run project, it's giving errors:

> Base Directory: D:\work\griffon\soms Running script
>   C:\Griffon-1.2.0\scripts\RunApp.groovy Resolving dependencies...
>   Dependencies resolved in 633ms. Environment set to development
>   Resolving framework plugin dependencies ... Framework plugin
>   dependencies resolved in 1114 ms. Resolving plugin dependencies ...
>   Plugin dependencies resolved in 741 ms.  [griffonc] Compiling 1 source
>   file to d:\Users\akarasaev.griffon\1.2.0\projects\soms\classes\main
>   Launching application ... 2013-04-15 10:26:44,788 [main] INFO 
>   griffon.swing.SwingApplication - Initializing all startup groups:
>   [login] 2013-04-15 10:26:46,311 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder - An error occurred
>   while building soms.LoginView@34a083f2
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CENTER for
>   class: org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder   at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.getProperty(UberBuilder.groovy:187)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.getProperty(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:210)
>     at soms.LoginView.run(LoginView.groovy:18)  at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:152)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:160)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)
>   2013-04-15 10:26:46,324 [main] ERROR
>   griffon.util.GriffonExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CENTER for
>   class: org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder   at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.getProperty(UberBuilder.groovy:187)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.getProperty(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:210)
>     at soms.LoginView.run(LoginView.groovy:18)  at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:152)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:160)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)

The same error happens when I try to run from command prompt.

Environment:

1. Win 7 Pro, 64-bit
2. IntelliJ IDEA ver 12.1
3. Griffon-1.2.0 JDK 1.6

**LoginModel.groovy**:

```
package soms

import groovy.beans.Bindable
import griffon.transform.PropertyListener
import static griffon.util.GriffonNameUtils.isBlank

@Bindable
@PropertyListener(enabler)
class LoginModel {
    String login
    String password
    boolean submitEnabled
    boolean resetEnabled

    private enabler = { e ->
        submitEnabled = !isBlank(login) && !isBlank(password)
        resetEnabled =  !isBlank(login) || !isBlank(password)
    }
}
```

**LoginView.groovy**:

```
package soms

application(title: 'Login',
        preferredSize: [320, 240],
        pack: true,
        locationByPlatform: true
)

borderLayout()
panel(constraints: CENTER, border: emptyBorder(6)) {
    gridLayout(rows:3, columns:2, hgap:6, vgap:6)

    label: 'login:'
    textField columns: 20, text: bind(target: model, 'login', mutual: true)

    label: 'password:'
    textField columns: 20, text: bind(target: model, 'password', mutual: true)
}

panel(constraints: SOUTH){
    gridLayout(rows:1, cols:2, hgap:6, vgap:6 )
    button('reset', actionPerformed: controller.reset, enabled: bind{model.resetEnabled})
    button('submit', actionPerformed: controller.reset, enabled: bind{model.submitEnabled})
}
```

**LoginController.groovy**:

```
package soms

class LoginController {
    def model
    def view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my LoginController.groovy was incomplete.
Now it's working and the correct LoginController.groovy as follows:

```
package soms

import griffon.transform.Threading

class LoginController {
    def model
    def view

    @Threading(Threading.Policy.SKIP)
    def reset = {
        model.login = ''
        model.password = ''
    }
    def submit = {
        println "Login: ${model.login}"
        println "Password: ${model.password}"
    }
}
```